# Box align with other boxes

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see, that box has less height and I wanted the bottom one to stack with it, is it possible to do it? Any help will be appreciated.

This is the css I have:

```
<style>
div{
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You could probably use flex for this?

Comment: something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45753790/align-images-on-each-other

Comment: @AndyHolmes Can you please explain better? I don't know much about flex

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ - this will help you

Comment: You can achieve this with two approaches: either you use flex or display: grid. Here's a tutorial/guide how to use grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: @Neil That's exacly what I need, but I looked it up and it's kinda confusing, can you explain it better and add an example?

Comment: People won't code the thing for you, the 2 links should give you plenty of insight on how to do this

Comment: @AndyHolmes Flex doens't really work for me, so I'll try the grid

Comment: @maverick I didn't quite understand the grid option, it doesn't show something i need, no example of how to align like I needed.

Comment: This question is too often asked. What you want is something called "masonry". Google for that or search for it here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=masonry

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Comment: See my answer! I've linked two jsfiddle with how display: flex works and how display: grid works. Either way you choose, it should help solve your question. @BrunoMoutinho

Answer (score 2):

Just use flex's rule `align-items: center`.

See [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for more details.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and link only answers are not allowed. Either use information from the link to form your own answer or delete this altogether. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer